# Does breezejs look automatically in the cache for an already done server query

Tags: breeze

When I do a query to my WebApi controller action which passes a viewmodel with 2 properties:

Id = 1
date = 01/01/2013

and this data is cached by breeze.

The next query I do has the same id but the date is different.

Now I ask myself does breeze automatically look into the local cache when the user retrieves

data for the above 2 queries or does breeze go to the server?

Does breeze also take the data from the local cache when I do:

- execute query no. 1
- change a textfield in the resulting data and save that
- execute query no. 2
- execute query no. 1 again and ask myself, does breezejs go to the server or take the data

automatically from its cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breeze always goes to the server by default.  You can change this by either using the  FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache or by performing executeQueryLocally.

As a result of any server queries, the cache is always updated.

Comment: and when I use .FromLocalCache explicitly and breeze finds no data in it, does it go automatically to the server and search there?

Comment: No. You must be explicit when telling Breeze where to look. The one slight exception is [**EntityManager.fetchEntityByKey**](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_fetchEntityByKey) which has an option to look in cache first and then resolve from the server if not found in cache.